# How to view all layers / resolutions of a .ico favicon / icon?

Tags: favicon

I would like to test my favicon to see all of its layers but don't want to install software. Is there a way to do that in a browser? Is there an online tool that accepts a .ico URL then shows you its contents? If not, would it be possible for me or someone to make such a tool?

The reason I'm asking is because I was sure that I included a 192x192 layer in my favicon but the Google favicon API renders that particular resolution as the default 16x16.

Answer (score 3):

This online tool works for me:
https://redketchup.io/icon-editor

You can see the different layers like so:

[image: Screenshot of https://redketchup.io/icon-editor]

Comment: Seems like you can only load local files and not give it a URL. Do you know why my favicon wouldn't have a 192 size for the Google API even though this tool shows that it exists? For example: https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&sz=192